# Как начать пользоваться beta версией golang?

Tags: golang

Хотел в своём пет-проекте пощупать дженерики в Golang, но не могу найти информацию о том, как переключиться на версию в стадии beta.

Скачал версию вот так:

```
go install golang.org/dl/go1.18beta1@latest
```

Теперь пытаюсь понять, как переключить мой проект на неё.

Пробовал прописать в `go.mod` версию 1.18, но после этого при компиляции оно требует сделать `go mod tidy`, а эта команда говорит `go.mod file indicates go 1.18, but maximum supported version is 1.17`

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался.

Надо было вместо

```
go mod tidy
```

запускать

```
go1.18beta1 mod tidy
```